# How to convert an json data in array using accessor method in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, accessor

I m new in Laravel 8. Please give any suggestion for the given below code or answer my question:
Given below is my code an example of what i really want to get:
my data is :

```
[{"column_1_1":"value_1_1","column_1_2":"value_1_2"},{"column_2_1":"value_2_1","column_2_2":"value_2_2"}]
```

and I want

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [column_1_1] => value_1_1
            [column_1_2] => value_1_2
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [column_2_1] => value_2_1
            [column_2_2] => value_2_2
        )
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bro you just need to add the accessor method in your model like:

Guess you have xyz column in your database

```
public function getXyzAttribute($xyz)
{
    return json_decode($xyz);
}
```

It will directly return the array.

Hope it worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this answer as the other is showing only one way and is the least used... Mine is the Laravel way, the one you should always use and the most you are going to see all the time...

If you have a Model who's property is, for example, `data`, you don't have to overwrite how it is read by doing `getDataAttribute` and use `json_decode`...

If that property/field is a JSON/TEXT in your database (hence storing JSON), you just have to [`cast`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) it.

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

So later you can do:

```php
foreach ($model->data as $item) {
    ...
}
```

And store info in it like:

```php
$array = ['products' => ['item1', 'item2'], 'quantity' => 2];

$model->data = $array;
```

And it will get saved on the database like `{products: ["item1", "item2"], quantity: 2}`

Comment: I dont want to store data in array form. Want to store data in only json format. And above answer is working fine for me.

Comment: Where do you want to store data ? In your database ? Then my answer is the best one, is how Laravel handles this stuff, the other one is also correct but is not the best one. If you see a senior dev, you will see my answer. Do what you want with your code, I am just trying to give you the BEST answer so you don't get used to use create methods like `getSomethingAttribute` and use `json_decode` inside and then create `setSomethingAttribute` and use `json_encode` inside...

Comment: I really appriciated. thanx for your concern.